# mysql join with min value inside group by

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am attempting to write a query.

**My table is:**

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id |    date    |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-04-01 |
|  2 |       1 | 2017-01-01 |
|  3 |       1 | 2018-07-01 |
|  4 |       2 | 2018-09-01 |
|  5 |       2 | 2018-05-01 |
|  6 |       3 | 2018-10-01 |
|  7 |       1 | 2012-01-01 |
|  8 |       3 | 2016-06-01 |
|  9 |       3 | 2011-01-01 |
| 10 |       1 | 2000-01-01 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | user_id |    date    | first_login |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-04-01 | 2000-01-01  |
|  2 |       1 | 2017-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
|  3 |       1 | 2018-07-01 | 2000-01-01  |
|  4 |       2 | 2018-09-01 | 2018-05-01  |
|  5 |       2 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-01  |
|  6 |       3 | 2018-10-01 | 2011-01-01  |
|  7 |       1 | 2012-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
|  8 |       3 | 2016-06-01 | 2011-01-01  |
|  9 |       3 | 2011-01-01 | 2011-01-01  |
| 10 |       1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible ?
it seems to me that it's a combination of joins !

I tried that, but it does not work. the execution is endless.

```
CREATE TABLE CONNEXIONS
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `date` date)
;

INSERT INTO CONNEXIONS
    (`id`, `user_id`, `date`)
  VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-04-01'),
    (2, 1, '2017-01-01'),
    (3, 1, '2018-07-01'),
    (4, 2, '2018-09-01'),
    (5, 2, '2018-05-01'),
    (6, 3, '2018-10-01'),
    (7, 1, '2012-01-01'),
    (8, 3, '2016-06-01'),
    (9, 3, '2011-01-01'),
    (0, 1, '2000-01-01')
  ;


SELECT  conn.*, c.first_login
FROM CONNEXIONS AS conn

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(conn.date) AS first_login, user_id
    FROM CONNEXIONS AS conn
    GROUP BY conn.user_id
) c ON (conn.user_id = c.user_id)
```

edit:
I made some mistake in the query, MAX instead of MIN and client_id instead of user_id.

Comment: "but it does not work" - what does that mean? Do you get any error message? And what is 'client_id'?

Comment: I made some omissions in my question(user_id/client_id, MIN/MAX), but the subject of my question is rather on the joins.
I edited my question.
Thank you

Comment: Although not always necessary, I think it's good practice to always include all subquery columns in the join criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I believe that the `first_login` will be the minimum connection date, not the maximum.
- You aliasing was misplaced. I have fixed it.

Try:

```
SELECT  conn1.*, c.first_login
FROM CONNEXIONS AS conn1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(conn2.date) AS first_login, conn2.user_id
    FROM CONNEXIONS AS conn2
    GROUP BY conn2.user_id
) c ON (conn1.user_id = c.user_id)
```

---

**Result**

```
| id  | user_id | date       | first_login |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | ----------- |
| 1   | 1       | 2013-04-01 | 2000-01-01  |
| 2   | 1       | 2017-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
| 3   | 1       | 2018-07-01 | 2000-01-01  |
| 4   | 2       | 2018-09-01 | 2018-05-01  |
| 5   | 2       | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-01  |
| 6   | 3       | 2018-10-01 | 2011-01-01  |
| 7   | 1       | 2012-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
| 8   | 3       | 2016-06-01 | 2011-01-01  |
| 9   | 3       | 2011-01-01 | 2011-01-01  |
| 0   | 1       | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01  |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iey8gvhvKFQzhKq5xeXy38/0)

Comment: @oussaka Did you check the DB fiddle ? I am getting same results as yours expected

Comment: Check your DB Fiddle URL.

Comment: @oussaka check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iey8gvhvKFQzhKq5xeXy38/0

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I thought about doing the same thing before posting the question !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `correlated` subquery & you need `MIN()` instead of `MAX()` :

```
SELECT CONN.*,
       (SELECT MIN(conn1.date)
        FROM CONNEXIONS conn1
        WHERE conn1.user_id = conn.user_id
       ) AS first_login
FROM CONNEXIONS conn;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `min()` instead `max()` and you need to group by user_id

```
SELECT  conn.*, c.first_login
FROM CONNEXIONS

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT min(conn.date) AS first_login, user_id
    FROM CONNEXIONS AS conn
    GROUP BY conn.user_id
) c ON (conn.user_id = c.user_id)
```

Comment: thank you but the question was rather about the join, not about MIN / MAX

Answer (score 0):

It is worth pointing out that in MySQL 8+, you would use standard window functions:

```
SELECT c.*,
       MIN(c.date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.user_id) as first_login
FROM CONNEXIONS c;
```